# How to sort using jQuery Facebook multi-friend-selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using a jQuery Multi-Friend Selector form this site;
http://mike.brevoort.com/2010/08/10/introducing-the-jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector-plugin/

And it works great for what i need, except it does not sort the friends alphabetically. I have isolated where the friends are being pulled from facebook, but have no clue how to sort them.  Any ideas?

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
    $.each(response.data, function(i, friend) {
      $("#jfmfs-friend-container").append("<div class='jfmfs-friend' id='" + friend.id  +"'><img src='https://graph.facebook.com/" + friend.id + "/picture' /><div class='friend-name'>" + friend.name + "</div></div>");
    });
  init();
});
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: i think, what you can do is...store the friend.name in array, and sort that array using array.sort(), then display them..actually i don't know what the friend is? so i am giving this idea based on my own understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just so everyone benefit.  I sorted the names by using this code;

```
function sortByName(a, b) {
    var x = a.name.toLowerCase();
    var y = b.name.toLowerCase();
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
}

FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {        
   _friend_data = response.data.sort(sortByName);
   $.each(response.data, function(i, friend) {
    $("#jfmfs-friend-container").append("<div class='jfmfs-friend' id='" + friend.id  +"'><img src='https://graph.facebook.com/" + friend.id + "/picture' /><div class='friend-name'>" + friend.name + "</div></div>");
    });
    init();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes I faced the same problem but I guess facebook does not provide any parameter through which you can get sorted friend lists.

However as suggested by Vivek above store the friends in an array and then sort that array and display it.

In this case instead of sorting the array I provided the text box in the popup above to enter the search string may be a name and show friends accordingly. i.e. you already fetch the friend list and do the iteration.

Thanks
Deepak